# how to generate random tuples with a string included

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

My goal is to be able to generate random tuples consisting of 3 variables. 2 be float(x,y coordinates ) and the last one a string. Each tuple should have the format of (float, float, string). I'm pretty sure the x,y is easy but i'm unsure if its possible to generate a string as the third parameter. The string should be a random choice of within a set. 
For example say I have a list of strings **["one", "two" , "three"]**. I would want my generated tuple to consist of two random floats and one of the strings within that set. I was thinking something similar to this code below

```
[(randint(0, 180), randint(0, 180)) for _ in range(100)]
```

Once again just to clarify i am just trying to figure out if its possible to add one the strings from the set as my 3rd variable in my tuple

Comment: Yeah someone said that already . no need to duplicate responses ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html)

```
import random
strings = ['one', 'two', 'three']
[(random.randint(0, 180), random.randint(0, 180), random.choice(strings)) for _ in range(100)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

```
[(randint(0, 180), randint(0, 180)) for _ in range(100)]
```

This does not generate random floats, it insteads generate random integers as evident by the function name.
Instead:

```
[(uniform(0, 180), uniform(0, 180), choice(["one,"two","three"]) for _ in range(100)]
```

Note:

random.uniform generates a random float within range(0,180)

random.choice selects a random element from ["one","two","three"]

Comment: good catch . that was silly of me . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could get random number for the index of the list of strings and use that to get the random string

```
list_of_strings = ["one", "two" , "three"]

print [(randint(0, 180), randint(0, 180), list_of_strings[randint(0, len(list_of_strings) -1 )]) for _ in range(100)]
```